# poisson-binomial mixture tail bound

Tags: probability

Let $X \sim \operatorname{Binom}[(n,p)]$ and $Y \sim \operatorname{Poisson}[f(X)]$, where f is a convex function. Are there any good tail bounds for $Y$? For instance, are there any Chernoff-style bounds for $Y$?

Comment: The article "The moment bound is tighter than Chernoff's bound for positive tail probabilities", referenced at [this post](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/66403/about-bound-based-on-r-th-central-moment) may be of interest.

Answer (score 2):

The Cheroff's bound, for positive random variable, and arbitrary $\theta$ such that the moment generating function $\mathcal{M}_Y(\theta)$ exists:
$$
  \mathbb{P}(Y \ge t) \le \mathrm{e}^{-\theta t} \mathcal{M}_Y(\theta)   =  \mathbb{E} \left( \mathrm{e}^{-\theta t + f(X) \left( \mathrm{e}^\theta - 1 \right))}  \right)
$$

If $g_\theta(X) = \mathrm{e}^{-\theta t + f(X) \left( \mathrm{e}^\theta - 1 \right))}$ happens to be *concave*, then by [Jensen's inequality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jensen%27s_inequality) we would have:
$$
   \mathbb{P}(Y \ge  t) \le  \mathrm{e}^{-\theta t + f( \mathbb{E} \left(X\right)) \left( \mathrm{e}^\theta - 1 \right))}  = \mathrm{e}^{-\theta t + f( n p ) \left( \mathrm{e}^\theta - 1 \right))} 
$$

The inequality above would be true for any such $\theta$ that $g_\theta^{\prime\prime}(X) \le 0$ for all $X \ge 0$:
$$
 0 \ge  g_\theta^{\prime\prime}(x) = g(x) \left\{ \left( f^\prime(x) ( \mathrm{e}^{\theta} - 1) \right)^2 + f^{\prime\prime}(x) ( \mathrm{e}^{\theta} - 1)  \right\}
$$

Alternatively one could look at the moment bound:

$$
  \mathbb{P}(Y > t) \le \frac{1}{t} \mathbb{E}(Y) = \frac{1}{t} \mathbb{E}(f(X))
$$

Again, if $f(x)$ is *concave*, by Jensen's inequality we would have
$$
    \mathbb{P}(Y > t) \le \frac{f(n p)}{t}
$$